# How to view the content of a mercurial bundle without a repository

Tags: mercurial, bundle

Is there a way to see the content of a mercurial bundle WITHOUT having a repository?

I usually would do

```
cd $MYREPO
hg in -p ../bundle
```

However, sometimes this would complain

```
abort: 00changelog.i@f8261a6e2cb2: unknown parent!
```

The thing is, I don't even want to apply the bundle. Or, I could be travelling and don't have a repo handy. I just want to see its contents of the bundle file. Why why why does it have to be a binary file and impossible to be read by a human???

Answer (score 4):

A bundle is an overlay repository (emphasis on overlay). It is designed to be a space-efficient binary delta encoding between two repositories that has traditionally been used for push and pull operations, but has seen other applications since then.

The bundle format cannot in general be decoded without access to one of the two repositories the bundle was derived from. This is because internally, everything is represented as a binary delta; you may not even be able to derive textual patches from the binary delta (which usually require context from the original version not contained in the bundle). On top of that, even manifests (i.e. the lists of files in revisions) are encoded this way. You can retrieve *some* meta information, but generally not enough to be useful.

If you need a human readable format, you should use `hg export` instead of `hg bundle`; this is a textual format that also encodes all the meta data for commits (ancestry, committer, date, node id) and can be imported into matching repositories (`hg import --exact`).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to see the content of a mercurial bundle WITHOUT having a repository?

It's ... well... rather tricky, because partial bundle contains only *deltas* and, obviously, you **must** to provide parent(s) for calculations

> I usually would do

Wrong way, definitely. If `$MYREPO` is (not-empty) fork of repo in `default` path, you will be happy with *single small* change: `hg in --bundle ../bundle` (see [Looking into bundle files](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/LookingIntoBundles) wiki-page)

> The thing is, I don't even want to apply the bundle.

Irrelevant. You may want not apply bundle, but have to have repository with at least bundle's base changeset

> Or, I could be travelling and don't have a repo handy. I just want to see its contents of the bundle file.

You can try (old - from 2008 year, hackery, unmaintained) to use [extension](https://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2008-March/017981.html), created for exactly this task (I'll recommend to read the whole topic "Look into a bundle file" anyway), but - having repo may be a lot easier way:

```
hg-git>hg log -R z:\bundlefile -r bundle()
changeset:   951:a593069575bb
user:        Augie Fackler <raf@durin42.com>
date:        Wed Nov 25 17:52:59 2015 -0500
summary:     git_handler: work around dulwich using unicode for ref names

changeset:   952:584961625a58
bookmark:    master
tag:         tip
user:        Siddharth Agarwal <sid0@fb.com>
date:        Tue Dec 01 10:19:50 2015 -0800
summary:     Backed out changeset a593069575bb
```

Comment: That extension also does not (and cannot) work without access to the underlying repository; it essentially provides the `-r bundle()` functionality.

Comment: @ReimerBehrends - as I understood message, extension must work with solo-bundles and without "abort: unknown parent!", maybe I'm wrong

Comment: I checked out the extension, it doesn't work without the underlying repository.